# Chern character of a Representation

Tags: rt.representation-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let $G$ be a finite group. Under the identification of the representation ring $R_{\mathbb{C}}(G)$ with the equivariant K-theory $KU^0_G(\ast)$ of the point,  followed by Atiyah-Segal completion-projection to the K-theory $KU^0(B G)$ of the classifying space

$$
  \widehat{(-)}
  \;:\;
  R_{\mathbb{C}}(G)
  \simeq
  KU_G^0(\ast)
    \longrightarrow
  KU^0(B G)
$$

every linear representation $V \in R_{\mathbb{C}}(G)$ induces a K-theory class $\widehat V \in KU^0(B G)$.

The former has a *character* $\chi_{V}$, the latter has a *Chern character* $\mathrm{ch}(\widehat V)$, or rather a sequence $c_n(\widehat V)$ of *Chern classes*.

Is there an algebraic expression of the Chern classes $\mathrm{c}_n(\widehat V)$ in terms of the character $\chi_V$?

Atiyah discussed this question way back in

- Michael Atiyah, 
  "Characters and cohomology of finite groups", 
  Publications Mathématiques de l’IHÉS, Volume 9 (1961) , p. 23-64 ([numdam](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1961__9__23_0))

in the appendix. There he gave an explicit formula for $c_1(\widehat{V})$ in terms of $\chi_V$, but about the other Chern classes, he wrote:

> It would be highly desirable to have a direct algebraic definition of them, but [...] this is still unsolved.

Is this still the case?

Comment: Doesn't Symonds' splitting principle for group representations solve the problem? If not, what would be missing?